# How to game-render a mesh through/behind other?

Tags: rendering, mesh, game-engine, materials, transparency

I was making a character with a manga like style, and It got to show the meshes of eye balls, eyebrow and eyelashes through the hair, but not throug the face skin or ny other parts of the mesh. Making an efect like in Zelda Wind Waker:

[image: Eyes through hair]

As a eyebrow and eyelashes are part of the mesh of hole body, because i need to make shapekeys on it. I tough this can be maked by adding diferent materials to this parts, Hair, Eyes and the rest of body
NOTE: The eye balls are separate objects, but I think I can join it on the main mesh if require it.

[image: this is my mesh]

I searched, and got similar efects. but in case of Wind Waker the Link's eyes are just flat decals, in mine, eyeballs are 3D mesh.
Can someone show me a way to make this?

Comment: A UV-Unwrapped or painted Alpha mask?

Comment: I thik it's both. I'll Use different material and unwarp a differnt texture with alpha channel just to stache, eyeleashes and eyebows, and eyeballs too, even though dont need to show alpha on the sphere, but just to avail the same material that will show behind the hair, if possible ..

Comment: Kind of... But I need it to show behind the hair only, and notice that all are part of the same mesh.

Comment: Have you had any success?

Comment: Not Yet. actualy o dont get in the part of texturing yet. I still modeling a Hi-res vertion for bake normalmaps. If I got the effect before someone show me, ill anwer my own question... Yhanks for the atention ( ^_^)

Comment: In blender internal you can adjust the z-offset - not sure if it works in BGE. Enable Z-Transparency and leave alpha at 1.0 then under Options increase Z Offset. It is a distance value so keep it small enough to get over the hair but not anything else that may get close to the head.

Comment: Nice! It might be a answer. Why did you not put as answer here? ( XD) I'll try later, tranks!
I Still on High-poly modeling, that takes a lot of work. shoo!

Comment: @sambler , I tried what you meant and did not work very well. It show through the hair but through the snout too because its near too. and I cant apply to the eye balls cause the sphere will show throug the face..
And only works on rendered mode.
The ideal is if were possible to choose the material that it will show through. and if were possible preview on material mode